# knockout.js dependent variable selects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

*[ Please see updates at the bottom ]*

I'm trying to make knockout depended selects, it's intended to make a "product" selection by these attributes, for example a product can have "size" and "material", if I selected "size", a knockout script make a request to the backend and retrieves which "material" available for the selected size, in other words, if an attribute is selected, other attributes are filtered out to show only available values ("all sizes": 1,2,3,4,5; "aluminium": 1,4).

Attributes list are completely dynamic, there are about 80 attributes which can be linked to the products in arbitrary way.

Are there any "best practices" for this situation?

I am trying to solve it with code like this, without success yet:

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = data;
    self.attributes = ko.observableArray();
    self.data.forEach(function(item, i, a) {
        // I passed .self to catch it later
        // in products as view_model.attributes().
        self.attributes.push(new VariableProduct(item, self));
    })
};

var VariableProduct = function(item, view_model) {
    var self = this;
    self.attribute_name = ko.observable(item.name);
    self.attribute_value = ko.observable('--');

    // list of attribute values
    self.attribute_values = ko.computed(function() {
        var result = {};
        view_model.attributes().forEach(function(attribute, i, a) {
            // here I try to filter each attributes lists by values
            // it doesn't work well
            if (attribute.attribute_name() != self.attribute_name() && self.attribute_value() != '--') {
                result = attribute.attribute_values().filter(
                        function(value) {
                            return value.indexOf(self.attribute_value()) >= 0;
                        });
            }
        });
        return result;
    });
};
```

**UPDATE 1:**
With Dnyanesh's reference to ko.subscribe(), i've achived these results, isn't ok yet, but a progress:

http://jsfiddle.net/xwild/65eq14p3/

**UPDATE 2:**
At the end it was solved with [knockout.reactor](https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor) and [knockout.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugins.

[Related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247444/knockout-mapping-data-from-server-lost-subscriptions) with details and the answer.

Comment: Interesting question, does it also need to work vice-versa? Eg if you select material, only the available sizes should be filtered in the size dropdown? Or are all 'attributes' linked to 1 dropdown (sizes) .. in other words: is "sizes" the only independant variable, and all others dependant or are all attributes inter-dependant?

Comment: Yes, about 10-15 filters are placed for each product and every select should react when other select is changed.

Comment: Without talking about the actual code, I think it might be useful to think thoroughly about the design. I suppose your output should be something like http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/models/laptops (go ahead & check some boxes); and I don't think it's wise to totally omit the options when non-selectable. Rather, make it clear to the visitor that his decision limits his choice by disabling checkboxes/ striking them through (see link). In short, I think you're better off using a `radio` or `checkbox` instead of `select`

Comment: I have too little space for all of these, actually selects are placed in product's divs, and there are 4 products per a row.
Now I'm trying to resolve it with ko.mapping, but also without success, subscriptions are lost when I update it :/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247444/knockout-mapping-data-from-server-lost-subscriptions

Answer (score 2):

For dependent select I think you can use subscribe in following manner

```js
var vm = {
        sizes: ko.observableArray([
            { name: 'size 1', id: 1},
            { name: 'size 2', id: 2},
            { name: 'size 3', id: 3},
            { name: 'size 4', id: 4}
        ]),
        selectedSize : ko.observable(0),
    
    };
        
          vm.selectedSize.subscribe(function(newValue){
              alert('Selected Size is ---> ' + newValue )
           // Here at this point call your ajax or backend method and bind the values which are coming form 
        });
      
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="
    options: sizes,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'id',
    value: selectedSize,
    optionsCaption: 'Choose Size...'"">
</select>
 
<select data-bind="
    options: material,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'id',
    value: selectedMaterial,
    optionsCaption: 'Choose Material...'"">
</select>
```

I know I am talking about only part of solution to your problem but, I think you need to divide your data object to bind it to various controls.

Comment: It looks like what I need, I'll try to make an example and post here.

Comment: That will be better so that I can undestand exact problem and can help you based on example.

Comment: some results here http://jsfiddle.net/xwild/65eq14p3/, isn't ok yet, now it's needed to select the first match of all other selects and avoid reccurent effects..

Comment: I am not getting what else need to be done. Which reccurent  effects you want to avoid?

Comment: each selects have to update all selects, and when other selects are updated - there is recursion and infinite requests count to a backend (I can't say to knockout "don't use subscriptions when I update values in the code").

Comment: I am curious about one thing that why you have made select in forech can not you have it differnt code will be eazily managle in that case. Is there any specific reason for that.

Comment: these selects are completely dynamic, actually some of them should be hidden after some values are selected, after a backend request