# Knockout mapping data from server, lost subscriptions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to represent multiple selects with its selected values from backend JSON to knockout view model.
And it's needed to retrieve this JSON when each select is changed, first time - all is ok, but if I apply mapping again (ko.mapping.fromJS(test_data, ViewModel)), all subscriptions are lost does anyone know how to avoid this situation?

jsfiddle (I don't know why selects don't have its values, without jsfiddle - all is ok):
http://jsfiddle.net/0bww2apv/2/

```
$(ViewModel.attributes()).each(function(index, attribute) {
    attribute.attribute_value.subscribe(function(name) {
        console.log('SUBSCRIBE', name);

        var send_data = {};
        $(ViewModel.attributes()).each(function (index, attribute) {
            send_data[attribute.attribute_name.peek()] = attribute.attribute_value.peek();
            if (attribute.attribute_value() === null) {
                send_data = null;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (send_data) {
            console.log('REQUEST TO BACKEND: ', ko.toJSON(send_data));
            ko.mapping.fromJS(test_data, ViewModel);

            // subscriptions is lost here !
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/0bww2apv/4/ let me know just in-case . cheers

Comment: argh, arguments order, thanks... subscriptions preserve now, but mapping doesn't work as intended, every select's update should reset all selects values, in other words every change should rewrite all selects to initial data,I've added a few console.log, you can see before/after data there, also "attribute_value"s are placed to wrong observables (but reads ok first time, strange).
http://jsfiddle.net/0bww2apv/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I've solved my own question with [knockout.reactor](https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor) plugin,
If we remove all auxiliary constructions, it will look like:

```
var ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(test_data);

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);

ko.watch(ViewModel, { depth: -1 }, function(parents, child, item) {
    // here we need to filter watches and update only when needed, see jsfiddle
    ko.mapping.fromJS(test_data2, {}, ViewModel);
});
```

This way we update selects and don't have troubles with subscription recursions.

full version (see console output for details): http://jsfiddle.net/r7Lo7502/